# Zoho Reports API - Error Code 7005

Tags: android, zoho

I got error code 7005 from Zoho Reports API after integrating okhttp into my Android app. There's virtually no help available online, but I have worked out the answer so will share it here.

The problem code turned out to be the **"file"** String in this code:

```
MultipartBody.Builder postBodyBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
postBodyBuilder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
postBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("file", tempFileToUpload.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), tempFileToUpload));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be **"ZOHO_FILE"**, like this:

```
MultipartBody.Builder postBodyBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
postBodyBuilder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
postBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("ZOHO_FILE", tempFileToUpload.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), tempFileToUpload));
```

Please post a comment if you would like to see more code.